# Cleaning a git branch with a poor-quality commit log

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

Rather than ask about specific git verbs (which the git documentation is based around), I'd like to ask what is the best approach for this particular task.

I have a git branch with an ugly commit log, due to having been forced to commit to test the app. Lots of commits like:

- Fix typo
- Do X for Foo team
- More cleanups after rename
- Undo X now Foo team has changed their mind

Luckily, all those commits are in a branch.

Before I merge that branch, I would like the opportunity to clean up the commit log, consolidating and reordering the commits. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is an [interactive rebase](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) :

```
git rebase -i master
```

You can edit messages, reorder commits, squash or skip some of them through this command.

Comment: This is exactly correct. Make sure you keep a reference to the original state of the branch though, either by writing down the commit ID or, more easily, checking out to a temporary branch which you then rebase vs master. `rebase -i` is very powerful and as such, delicate to handle.

Comment: You're right, it's a good advice. Usually before digging into an interactive rebase, I 'save' the original state by creating a 'TEMP' branch. It avoids me to keep in mind the reference of the commit (but the idea is the same, coming back to the original state if something does not happen like you expected).

Comment: Just check the `reflog` if you only want the option to undo your rebase and try again.